# How to Resolve "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/util/IdentitySet" Error in Struts2 with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jar

I am using Struts2 and Hibernate For developing web application(I am Fresher to this concept)..am getting Following Error in Console..Can any one tell me the reason for that Issue ?

Error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/util/IdentitySet

---

I have added this below jar files to my project:

```
antlr-2.7.6.jar

commons-collections-3.1.jar

commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar

commons-io-1.3.2.jar

commons-lang-2.3.jar

commons-logging-1.1.jar

dom4j-1.6.1.jar

ejb3-persistence-1.0.1.GA.jar

freemarker-2.3.13.jar

hibernate-3.0.1.jar

hibernate-commons-annotations-3.0.0.ga.jar

hibernate-validator-3.0.0.ga.jar

hsqldb-1.7.2.2.jar

javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar

jta-1.1.jar

junit-3.8.1.jar

log4j-1.2.15.jar

ognl-2.6.11.jar

slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar

slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar

spring-hibernate3-2.0.8.jar

struts2-convention-plugin-2.1.6.jar

struts2-core-2.1.6.jar

struts2-fullhibernatecore-plugin-1.4-GA.jar

xwork-2.1.2.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the class "IdentitySet" is available in version "hibernate-3.1.1.jar" please check this link http://www.findjar.com/class/org/hibernate/util/IdentitySet.html

Comment: Thanks for  you reply....That issue is resolved.But Getting "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/AnnotationConfiguration"...Error..

Comment: Follow the same approach, you could go to www.findjar.com and search for classes that is missing and pick the latest jar files. Check this link for your new issue. http://www.findjar.com/class/org/hibernate/cfg/AnnotationConfiguration.html

Comment: Also, accept the answer if it has worked, so this question is closed